# Feature extraction using caffe model

Tags: neural-network, computer-vision, deep-learning, caffe

I'd like to discuss feature extraction using Caffe model called GoggleNet.
I am referring to this paper ["End to end people detection in crowded scenes"](https://arxiv.org/abs/1506.04878). For those who are familiar with caffe, should be able to cope with my queries.

The paper has its own [library](https://github.com/Russell91/ReInspect) using Python, I also run through the library but can't cope with some points mentioned in the paper.

The input image is passed through with `GoogleNet till inception_5b/output` layer.

Then output is formed as multidimensional array in 15x20x1024. So each 1024 vector represents a bounding box in the center of 64x64 region. Since it is 50% overlapping, there are 15x20 matrix for 640x480 image and each cell has third dimension of 1024 vector in length.

My query is

(1)how this 15x20x1024 array output can be obtained?

(2)how this 1x1x1024 data can represent 64x64 region in the image?
There is a description in the source code as

```
"""Takes the output from the decapitated googlenet and transforms the output
    from a NxCxWxH to (NxWxH)xCx1x1 that is used as input for the lstm layers.
    N = batch size, C = channels, W = grid width, H = grid height."""
```

That conversion is implemented using the function in Python as

```
def generate_intermediate_layers(net):
    """Takes the output from the decapitated googlenet and transforms the output
    from a NxCxWxH to (NxWxH)xCx1x1 that is used as input for the lstm layers.
    N = batch size, C = channels, W = grid width, H = grid height."""

    net.f(Convolution("post_fc7_conv", bottoms=["inception_5b/output"],
                      param_lr_mults=[1., 2.], param_decay_mults=[0., 0.],
                      num_output=1024, kernel_dim=(1, 1),
                      weight_filler=Filler("gaussian", 0.005),
                      bias_filler=Filler("constant", 0.)))
    net.f(Power("lstm_fc7_conv", scale=0.01, bottoms=["post_fc7_conv"]))
    net.f(Transpose("lstm_input", bottoms=["lstm_fc7_conv"]))
```

I can't cope that portion as how each 1x1x1024 represents that size of bounding box rectangle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are looking at a 1x1 cell very deep in the net, it's effective [recptive field](https://www.quora.com/What-is-a-receptive-field-in-a-convolutional-neural-network) is quite large and can be (and probably is) 64x64 pixels in the original image.
That is, each feature in `"inception_5b/output"` is affected by 64x64 pixels in the input image.

Comment: Means that level output could be 15x20x1024. Due to receptive field, each 1x1x1024 represents 64x64 rectangle size in the image?

Comment: Is there any good reference for this explanation? Thanks for the reference in Quora, any deeper discussion than that?

Comment: @batuman no "canonical" reference I can think of at the moment. feel free to edit the answer with a link if you find a good one :)

Comment: Thanks the link (http://cs231n.github.io/convolutional-networks/) on the same page you mentioned has quite lengthy explanation and quite worth of reading the document. The thing I understood after reading the document is that 15x20x1024 represents 139x139 respective field size in the original image. Since the original image is 640x480, then that 15x20 spatial output represents 64x64 bounding boxes with 50% overlapping. That is what I coped for the description in the paper. That means if I try to produce 30x60 spatial output will represents 32x32 bounding boxes, if I want to scale down.